# SQL Server GROUP BY duplicate values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a NOTOK table that containts  idproductype and idcause columns and a query that looks like this

```
SELECT pt.Name, c.Description 
FROM NOTOK n
JOIN ProductType pt ON n.IDProductType = pt.ID
JOIN Cause c ON n.IDCause=c.ID
```

That returns the following dataset

**PRODUCTTYPE**        **CAUSE**
productType1            cause1
productType1            cause1
productType1            cause1
productType1            cause2
productType1            cause2
productType1            cause3
productType2            cause1
productType2            cause1
productType3            cause3
productType3            cause3
productType3            cause1

Now, i'd like to group this by the ProductType-column and put the most common two causes in different column, so the results is as following

**PRODUCTTYPE**       **CAUSE1**       **CAUSE2**
productType1       cause1            cause2
productType2       cause1            NULL
productType3       cause3            cause1

How would i do that?

Comment: Can you explain more on what you are trying to achieve. It doesn't really make sense to have two columns of the most common causes containing information about other causes.

Comment: I want to generate a stored procedure where I want to get the two most common causes of products in this table are not ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `cte` to get the most common and use `ROW_NUMBER` to provide a way of getting the top 2 causes per product. This can then be pivoted to the result set you require.

```
WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT *, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY product_type ORDER BY n DESC ) o
 FROM (
  SELECT product_type, cause, COUNT(1) n
  FROM notok
  GROUP BY product_type, cause
 ) t
)

SELECT product_type, MAX([1]), MAX([2])
FROM cte
PIVOT (
  MAX(cause)
  FOR o IN ([1],[2])
) p
GROUP BY product_type
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07d01/13)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment I made to the now-deleted answer by Amirreza about not requiring `PIVOT`, here's an example based on TI's answer but without `PIVOT`.

Note that this is just for illustration, the `PIVOT`-based solution yields a more efficient query plan.

```
WITH cteCause AS (
 SELECT *, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY product_type ORDER BY n DESC ) o
 FROM (
  SELECT product_type, cause, COUNT(1) n
  FROM notok
  GROUP BY product_type, cause
 ) t
)
SELECT
  t.product_type,
  (SELECT c.cause FROM cteCause c WHERE c.product_type=t.product_type AND c.o=1) cause1,
  (SELECT c.cause FROM cteCause c WHERE c.product_type=t.product_type AND c.o=2) cause2
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT product_type FROM notok) t
```

(Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07d01/16).)